# Reference Request: Classification of spherical varieties by "Weyl group invariant fans"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, reductive-groups, toric-varieties, spherical-varieties

Apologies in advance for the vague question.

Let $X$ be a spherical variety with the action of some reductive group $G$. I have been told in conversation several times that such spherical varieties can be classified using the action of a maximal torus $T$ in $G$, and a $W$-invariant fan, where $W$ is the Weyl group of $G$. I have not been able to find a reference in the literature that discusses this, nor do I know a completely precise statement. But if something along these lines is true it would be very helpful to me.

To clarify, I am aware of Luna-Vust's classification of spherical $G$-varieties with open orbit $G/H$, using colored fans. However I do not see how that theory would relate to a $W$-invariant fan. I am also aware that when $G/H$ is a symmetric space that for the Luna-Vust classification one can describe the relevant data in terms of a 'little Weyl group', an involution invariant torus, and a restricted root system. Though I don't think this is what people mean when they talk about classifying spherical varieties as I said above.